How to allow only specific workflows
I would like to tighten the security of the GitHub Actions pipeline as it involves self-hosted runners. At the moment, there are in place all the generic steps like allowing only trusted users and disabling the runs from forks.
Now I would like to prevent any workflows from running unless they are explicitly allowed.
I am working with the GitHub Enterprise 3.13.
From what I tried I can, as any repository developer could, create a branch, create a on-push or on-pull-request workflow there and push the branch to the repo and create a PR for that. This, or after one modification of this new branch, the newly created workflow is triggered.
At this point I would like to allow only known/approved workflows, like Build/Test workflow from the master at a specified commit revision. And nothing else until it is added to the list.
I read some suggestions like run the actions only on protected (master) branch and control access to the branch via PR approval; however, I need to run some actions prior to PR approval (like build/test/coverage/etc.) The Codeowner settings is the same case - it can prevent the code from merging to protected branch but it does not prevent from creating a new one in anew branch.
I tried to use the Actions permissions and Allow select actions, but that works only on the actions level but not on the workflow level.
Unfortunately, with this GitHub version I can't use the Rulesets based on a filename pattern.

What you're asking for would be a nightmare for any one trying to work on a workflow. That is, they would be unable to verify the workflow  was correct until after it was merged to the main branch. Further, if the workflow was broken, then the repo would be left in a state of being unable to merge other PRs, since it must run the (now) broken workflow successfully before merging.

@Dunes - I understand your concern. The rules I am asking for is mostly for the protection of the self-hosted runners. In addition, the workflows are managed by special users/team, regular developers need to only observe the output of the actions. If there were a way how to maintain workflow files outside of the code itself, that would be great.

You might be able to use pull_request_target to achieve what you want. If any workflow file is changed, you can run a job that always fails and so prevent the PR from being able to be merged. pull_request_target always runs from the target branch, and so will not run a workflow that hasn't already been merged into your repo. Though, I'm not sure how you would disable this workflow once enabled. Thus, effectively preventing any subsequent updates to your repo's workflows forever. Maybe only a direct push to the main branch to remove the pull request target workflow would stop it from running.
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - opened
      - reopened
    paths:
      - '.github/workflow/**'

jobs:
  reject_workflow_changes:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: /bin/false

The problem with this is that I do not know how to disable this workflow once enabled. Perhaps you could use reusable workflows from another repo with separate write permissions that targets a moveable branch rather than a tag. This would enable the workflow that a repo runs to be updated if needed. eg.
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  some-job:
    uses: <your-org>/<your-super-repo>/.github/workflows/some-job.yml@main

This requires you to shift any existing workflows to the <your-super-repo> repo, and port them to be reusable. See https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.15/actions/sharing-automations/reusing-workflows
You may find that using reusable workflows and leaving comments in the workflow that nothing should be changed is enough.
